# Relationship between entropy of a language and crossword puzzles (a comment from Claude Shannon)

Tags: probability, puzzle

> The redundancy of a language is related to the existence of crossword puzzles. If the redundancy is zero any sequence of letters is a reasonable text in the language and any two-dimensional array of letters forms a crossword puzzle. If the redundancy is too high the language imposes too many constraints for large crossword puzzles to be possible. A more detailed analysis shows that if we assume the constraints imposed by the language are of a rather chaotic and random nature, large crossword puzzles are just possible when the redundancy is 50%. If the redundancy is 33%, three-dimensional crossword puzzles should be possible, etc.

In this case, redundancy is defined as $1-R$ where $R$ is the relative entropy: the ratio of the entropy of a source over the maximum entropy possible with the same number of symbols. Recall that entropy is defined as

$$H = - \sum_i p_i\log p_i,$$

where the sum is over all $n$ symbols in the alphabet and $p_i$ is the probability of character $i$ occurring. Further, $R$ is defined as

$$ R = \frac{H}{\log n}.$$

I understand the first part of his comment, it's clear that if the redundancy is $0$ then any 2D grid is a valid crossword since all character combinations are valid. However, what is the explantion behind the last two parts: `large crossword puzzles are just possible when the redundancy is 50%. If the redundancy is 33%, three-dimensional crossword puzzles should be possible, etc.`.

I'd expect the way that `large` is defined is flexible here, but I assume it means that the words are nontrivially connected.

I'm looking for insight on how to define `large` in this case, and why we expect the needed reduction in redundancy as we increase in dimensions (in particular the $1/d$ scaling rule he suggests)

#### References

[1] Shannon, Claude Elwood. "A mathematical theory of communication." ACM SIGMOBILE mobile computing and communications review 5.1 (2001): 3-55. http://signallake.com/innovation/shannon1948.pdf

Comment: I wondered this myself when I read that passage, but never found the energy to pursue it.

Comment: It seems like it might be a statement about capacity. See Wolf, J. K. (2001) 2001 Shannon Lecture. Constrained sequences, crossword
puzzles and Shannon. IEEE Information Theory Society Newsletter 51 (3): 1–
7.

and this (seemingly unpublished?) draft: http://www.inference.org.uk/mackay/xword.pdf